# Handle infinite scrolling without Scrapy/Selenium/Spynner in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to **scrape** data from Trip.com, specifically this page [here](https://www.trip.com/hotels/list?city=724&countryId=107&checkin=2020/09/14&checkout=2020/09/15&optionId=724&optionType=IntlCity&directSearch=0&display=Mumbai&crn=1&adult=2&children=0&travelPurpose=0&ctm_ref=ix_sb_dl&domestic=0) . When you visit this page in browser it shows result of 20 hotels but as you scroll down more hotel details are loaded. Now what i want is to **scrape** data of first 50 hotels. But i am asked to not use Scrapy, Selenium. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript has to read these data from server when you scroll - so use `DevTools` (tab: `Network`) in Chrome/Firefox to see all requests to server when you scroll page (especially `XHR` requests) - and then use these urls in your code.

Comment: @furas Thanks a lot for the response. I want to do this dynamically for more than 50 search categories, so copying URL will be a very tedious task. Can you please provide a more dynamic approach

Comment: first use `DevTools` to see requests send to server when you scroll, next use this information in code. First 20 items get from original page, next 30 items from url which you find in DevTools. Usually browser sends also some information to server which also has to send in code - and there can be information about categories. You have to use `DevTools` to get information when you scroll in different categories and compare information to see what browser changes to get data from different category.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the DevTools and look at the Network tab you can see that a request goes out to `https://www.trip.com/restapi/soa2/16709/json/HotelSearch?` This endpoint returns the results in a JSON format.

The next step would be to reverse engineer and copy the request into Python using urllib, which is built into Python. This step might require some experience and knowledge of how HTTP requests work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes i figured out this part but now my concern is how to get the value of "testab" in the request header using requests. Also can you please explain a bit more on you answer about reverse engineering the request or point me in a direction

Comment: I recommend using a library called Requests which builds on top of urllib. To reverse engineer is to try and figure out the values are being sent and why. With requests you can send headers by doing something like `requests.post(url, headers={"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36"})` It all comes down to trial and error. It looks like the request uses cookies. So you want to uses a session to track that. The goal is to copy the request enough to get the results back.

Comment: I ma using requests only but it only return 20 names when i pass the URL, but i want 50 names, the rest of the 30 will be visible as i scroll down on the page. Can you please tell me how do i get 50 names using requests library